# (Reference request) Smoothness of desingularized polyharmonic Green kernel on closed manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, laplacian, zeta-functions

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a closed Riemannian manifold with Laplace–Beltrami $\Delta_g$. It is known that, for $s>0$, the resolvent $\mathcal G_s$ of $(-\Delta_g)^s$ has integral kernel, say $G_s$, satisfying
$$\left| G_{n/2}(x,y)+ c_n \log d(x,y) \right| \leq C_g$$
for some (unique) universal constant $c_n>0$ and some constant $C_g=C_g(M)$.
Is there some reference to the fact that the desingularized kernel
$$(x,y)\longmapsto G_{n/2}(x,y)+c_n \log d(x,y)$$
is smooth around $x=y$?

Note: it seems to me that this should follow from some facts in [1], but their arguments are somewhat sketchy, and I would rather like a textbook reference with a solid proof.

[1] S. Minakshisundaram, Å. Pleijel, *Some Properties of the Eigenfunctions of The Laplace-Operator on Riemannian Manifolds*, Canadian J. Math. 1949